# How to resolve Warning: known event handler property `onExited`. It will be ignored in StatusSnackbar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In StatusSnackbar component getting Warning: known event handler property `onExited`, how to resolve the same.

**Component:**

```
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import NotificationType from '../../../../types/notification'
import styles from './styles'


const Component = ({
    classes,
    notification,
    onRemove: removeNotification
}) => {

    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(true)

    const handleClose = useCallback((e, reason) => {
        if (reason !== 'clickaway') {
            setOpen(false)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Snackbar
            className={classes.root}
            anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
            autoHideDuration={notification.duration}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            onExited={removeNotification}
            message={notification.message}
            variant={notification.variant}
        />
    )
}

Component.displayName = 'Notifications.Notification'
Component.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.shape({
        root: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    notification: NotificationType.isRequired,
    onRemove: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Component)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced onExited by onClose in following way and it working as I expected way without any warning.

**Component:**

```
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import NotificationType from '../../../../types/notification'
import styles from './styles'


const Component = ({
    classes,
    notification,
    onRemove: removeNotification
}) => {

    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(true)

    const handleClose = useCallback((e, reason) => {
        if (reason !== 'clickaway') {
            setOpen(false)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Snackbar
            className={classes.root}
            anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
            autoHideDuration={notification.duration}
            open={open}
            onClose={removeNotification}
            onClick={handleClose}
            message={notification.message}
            variant={notification.variant}
        />
    )
}

Component.displayName = 'Notifications.Notification'
Component.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.shape({
        root: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    notification: NotificationType.isRequired,
    onRemove: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Component)
```